Raspi 5 power usage while beeing switched off
According to my battery my Raspi 5 (with SSD) consumes more than 1 W while being switched off.

Why is the power usage so high and how can I reduce it?
If the answer is: pull the plug, the new power switch of the Raspi 5 would be useless. I am looking for another solution.

By default the SoC doesn't actually enter low power mode when shutdown on the Pi 4/5; I believe this has to do with some HAT and peripheral issues that don't really affect most users (specifically, if the 5V rail is still on while the 3.3V rail is off, which is what low power mode amounts to).
It can be changed via the EEPROM configuration; you can see the current values this way:
> rpi-eeprom-config 
[all]
BOOT_UART=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0
BOOT_ORDER=0xf41

You want to change POWER_OFF_ON_HALT to 1, which you can do with sudo -E rpi-eeprom-config --edit.
For more about that: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-bootloader-configuration

After changing the option the power usage did go down to 0.1 W.
